# JQuery .load() в цикле For работает не совсем логично...

Tags: jquery

Приветствую всех.

Пытаюсь выполнить следующий код, но он работает ни так, как мне нужно:

```
if(условие){
    $('body').append("<div id='loaddiv'><div>");
    for(var i=1; i<=100; i++){
        var dl = 0;
        $('#loaddiv').load('/script/?p='+i);
        dl = $('#loaddiv .standart-view tr').length;
        alert(dl);
    }
}
```

Таким образом, я должен получить количество tr-элементов, родителем которого является элемент с классом standart-view, а его родитель - div блок c id = load214235, для каждой страницы, НО постоянно выводятся нули в алерте :( Я пытался модернизировать код, добавив весь код в callback функцию лоада, чтобы все загрузилось, а потом выполнится остальная часть кода, но все та же не работающая хрень получается (он отказывается видеть dl)...

```
if(условие){
    $('body').append("<div id='loaddiv'><div>");
    for(var i=1; i<=100; i++){
        var dl = 0;
        $('#loaddiv').load('/folder/?p='+i, function(){
            dl = $('#loaddiv .standart-view tr').length;
            alert(dl);
        });
    }
}
```

+у меня после load еще должно идти условие с break; но firebug на него так же ругается, что break не знает, что закрывать... Как мне выйти из ситуации, не подскажете? Чувствую, что что-то намутил с видимостью переменных и данные не успевают подгрузиться с другой страницы, а скрипт летит впереди поровоза. Jquery подключен, весь остальной код рабочий, включая функции из jquery, иерархия элементов на другой странице соблюдена (кол-во tr должно находиться).

Comment: сделайте создаваемому диву закрывающий тег.

убедитесь в консоли, что в ответе на аякс-запрос вы получаете нечто содержащее .standart-view tr.

вы 100 раз делаете лоад в один и тот же див. это значит что в итоге див будет содержать последний загруженный ответ. не 100 ответов. не сотый ответ. а последний загруженный. вы точно этого хотели?

Comment: потому что асинхронно, break уже в callback выполняется, в общем гуглите "асинхронно javascript"

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)