# Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания

Tags: javascript, ajax, faq, javascript-faq

Пытаюсь делать вот так, но ничего не получается:

```
var result = "";

someInput.onchange = function() {
  result = someInput.value;
};

$.get("someapi", function (data) {
  result = data.foo;
});

some.api.call(42, function (data) {
  result = data.bar;
});

someDiv.textContent = result;
```

Почему-то в `someDiv` ничего не отображается.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/5000805

Answer (score 99, accepted):

### Дождались! [ES2017 8-ая редакция](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-async-function-definitions-static-semantics-Contains).

Внесено описание для функций с модификатором `async`, и использование `await`

Пример уже работает в хроме:

```js
(async function() {
  var data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  console.log(await data.json());
})();
```

---

### ES2015

В данном стандарте введено понятие [функции-генератора](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) - функции которая может передать управление из середины и затем вернуться в то же место. Обычно их используют для получения последовательностей

```
function* foo(){
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    while(true) yield 3;
}
```

Данная функция возвращает *итератор* для последовательности `1,2,3,3,3,...`, который может быть проитерирован. Хотя это интересно и само по себе, но есть один специфический случай.

Если получаемая последовательность - это последовательность действий, а не чисел, мы можем приостановить функцию всякий раз запуская действие и ждать результата, прежде чем вернуться к выполнению функции. Таким образом получаем не последовательность чисел, а последовательность *будущих значений*: т.е. *обещаний*.

Это несколько сложнее, но очень мощный трюк позволяет нам писать асинхронный код в синхронном режиме. Есть несколько "запускальщиков", которые делают это. Для примера будет использован `Promise.coroutine` из **Bluebird**, но есть и другие упаковщики, как `со` или `Q.async`.

```
var foo = coroutine(function*(){
    var data = yield fetch("/echo/json"); // обратите внимание на yield
    // код здесь будет выполнен после получения ответа на запрос
    return data.json(); // data здесь определена
});
```

Этот метод тоже возвращает обещание, которое может быть использовано в других сопрограммах. Например:

```
var main = coroutine(function*(){
   var bar = yield foo(); // ожидаем окончания нашей сопрограммы она вернет обещание
   // код ниже выполнится когда будет получен ответ от сервера
   var baz = yield fetch("/api/users/"+bar.userid); // зависит от результата возвращенного функцией foo
   console.log(baz); // выполнится когда завершатся оба запроса
});
main();
```

### <strike>ES2016 (ES7)</strike> Недалекое будущее

В стандартах есть намеки на введение новых ключевых слов `async`, `await` позволивших бы сделать работу с обещаниями более простой.

```
async function foo(){
    var data = await fetch("/echo/json"); // обратите внимание на await
    // код тут выполнится только после выполнения запроса
    return data.json(); // data определена
}
```

Но пока это просто [зарезервированные слова](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-future-reserved-words) и неизвестно попадут ли они в следующий стандарт и когда будут реализации.

На данный момент для их использования можно воспользоваться сборщиками, например [*Babel*](https://babeljs.io/).

<sub>[частичный перевод данного ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30180679/2881286)</sub>

Comment: Я бы особенно выделил вариант "**недалёкое будущее**", поэтому что из всех предложенных в ответах вариантов это единственный, который работает **во всех случаях** и при этом **самый читаемый**. Всё остальное — или попытка спрятать вермишель (именованные функции), или работает только в тривиальных случаях (промисы). Будущее за TypeScript.

Comment: @Squidward, к стати в последнем черновике они уже не просто слова:-)

Comment: Теперь это уже не недалёкое будущее :-)

Comment: Можно было бы обновить ответ, что это уже не недалёкое будущее.

Comment: @PetLinux, ответ уже был обновлен в августе 2018 года, с указанием что `async`, `await` заработали

Answer (score 140):

Проблема в том, что в коде нет операции ожидания. Ни подписка на событие, ни AJAX-вызов, ни даже вызов API не ждут поступления данных - а сразу же передают управление дальше. Поэтому строка `someDiv.textContent = result;` выполняется *ДО* того, как переменная `result` получит значение!

Способов сделать это присваивание после получения значения - несколько.

### Способ 0 - переместить присваивание внутрь

Возможно, этот способ выглядит как-то глупо - но он решает задачу и наиболее прост в понимании. Если ваше приложение достаточно простое - то так и надо делать. Смотрите:

```
someInput.onchange = function() {
  someDiv.textContent = someInput.value;
};

$.get("someapi", function (data) {
  someDiv.textContent = data.foo;
});

some.api.call(42, function (data) {
  someDiv.textContent = data.bar;
});

someDiv.textContent = "";
```

В данном случае я вообще избавился от переменной `result`.

Недостаток у данного способа ровно 1 - отсутствует разбиение на слои. Данные обрабатываются там же, где и получаются. Если вы чувствуете, что ваши скрипты становятся при использовании такого способа все менее понятными, или вам приходится писать одно и то же в нескольких местах - надо переходить к другим способам.

### Способ 0+ - вынесение присваивания в именованную функцию.

Простейшая модификация прошлого способа, позволяющая избавиться от дублирования кода.

```
someInput.onchange = function() {
  setResult(someInput.value);
};

$.get("someapi", function (data) {
  setResult(data.foo);
});

some.api.call(42, function (data) {
  setResult(data.bar);
});

setResult("");

function setResult(result) {
  someDiv.textContent = result;
}
```

Напомню, что в js объявления функций "поднимаются на верх", т.е. объявленной в самом низу функцией `setResult` можно пользоваться где угодно. Это позволяет начинать скрипт не с объявления 100500 функций - а с того кода, который непосредственно начнет выполняться.

Такой способ неплохо подходит для небольших скриптов, которые не разбиты на модули.

### *Проблема макаронного кода*

Иногда, асинхронный запрос делается в одном модуле или его части, а получить его результат надо в другой. Прямое использование способа 0+ приводит к коду, который называют "макаронным":

```
// модуль 1
function getResult() {
  $.get("someapi", function (data) {
    setResult(data.foo);
  });
}

// модуль 2
function someFunc() {
  getResult();
}
function setResult(result) {
  someDiv.textContent = result;
}
```

Обращаю внимание: `someFunc` вызывает `getResult`, которая вызывает `setResult`. В итоге два модуля вызывают друг друга. Это и есть макаронный код.

Для борьбы с таким кодом и предназначены способы ниже.

### Способ 1 - обратные вызовы ("колбеки", callbacks)

Добавим той функции, которая делает запрос, параметр `callback`, куда будем передавать функцию, получающую ответ:

```
function getResult(callback) {
  $.get("someapi", function (data) {
    callback(data.foo);
  });
}
```

Теперь такую функцию можно вызвать вот так:

```
getResult(function(result) {
  someDiv.textContent = result;
})
```

Или вот так:

```
getResult(setResult);

function setResult(result) {
  someDiv.textContent = result;
}
```

### Способ 2 - обещания ("промизы", promises)

Обещание в js - это шаблон программирования, обозначающий значение, которого сейчас нет, но предполагается, что оно будет в будущем.

Имеется несколько реализаций обещаний. Основной сейчас являются [ES6 Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), они поддерживаются современными браузерами кроме IE. (Но для тех браузеров, которые их не поддерживают, есть [куча полифилов](https://www.google.ru/search?q=es6+promise+polyfill)).

Создаются обещания вот так:

```
function getResult(N) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    some.api.call(N, function (data) {
      resolve(data.bar);
    });
  });
}
```

Также в качестве обещания можно использовать [JQuery Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
function getResult(N) {
  var d = $.Deferred();

  some.api.call(N, function (data) {
    d.resolve(data.bar);
  });

  return d.promise();
}
```

Или [Angular $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

```
function getResult(N) {
  var d = $q.defer();

  some.api.call(N, function (data) {
    d.resolve(data.bar);
  });

  return d.promise;
}
```

Кстати, Angular $q можно использовать и подобно es6 promise:

```
function getResult(N) {
  return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
    some.api.call(N, function (data) {
      resolve(data.bar);
    });
  });
}
```

В любом случае, использование такой функции getResult будет выглядеть одинаково:

```
getResult(42).then(function (result) {
  someDiv.textContent = result;
});
```

*Или же можно использовать новый синтаксис async/await, описанный в [ответе ниже от Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554337/178779)*

Обращаю внимание, что здесь я для примера взял именно `some.api.call`, но не событие или ajax-вызов - и это не случайно!

Дело в том, что обещание может быть выполнено (`resolved`) только 1 раз, а большинство событий происходят несколько раз. Поэтому использовать обещания для того же `onchanged` - нельзя.

Что же до ajax-вызова - то надо помнить, что он *УЖЕ* возвращает обещание! А потому все способы выше в комбинации с ним будут выглядеть смешными. Все делается гораздо проще:

```
function getResult() {
  return $.get("someapi")
    .then(function (data) {
      return data.foo;
    });
}
```

*Кстати, здесь тоже можно было использовать async/await*

На случай если вы запутались в коде выше, вот его "развернутая" версия:

```
function getResult() {
  var q1 = $.get("someapi");

  var q2 = q1.then(function (data) {
    return data.foo;
  });

  return q2;
}
```

Тут все просто. Сам по себе вызов `$.get` возвращает обещание, которое при выполнении будет содержать прищедшие с сервера данные.

Далее мы создаем для него продолжение, которое обработает эти данные (достанет поле `foo`).

Ну и потом это продолжение (которое тоже является обещанием) мы и возвращаем.

### Способ 3 - наблюдаемые значения (observables) в Knockout

Обычно про Knockout вспоминают как про библиотеку для двусторонней привязки данных к виду - но ее возможности могут пригодиться и при решении подобных задач.

Можно сделать так. Для начала, заведем наблюдаемое значение:

```
var result = ko.observable("");
```

Это значение можно менять по событию:

```
someInput.onchange = function() {
  // вызов result с параметром устанавливает значение равным параметру
  result(someInput.value);
};
```

И теперь можно выполнять некоторый блок кода каждый раз когда это значение меняется:

```
ko.computed(function() {
  // вызов result без параметров возвращает текущее значение
  someDiv.textContent = result();
});
```

Функция, переданная в `ko.computed`, будет вызвана каждый раз, когда ее зависимости изменятся.

PS код выше приведен как пример ручной работы с наблюдаемыми значениями. Но имейте в виду, что в Knockout есть более простые способы для работы с содержимым элементов DOM:

```
var vm = {
  result: ko.observable()
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<input data-bind="value: result"></input> <!-- бывший someInput -->

<div data-bind="text: result"></div> <!-- бывший someDiv -->
```

### Способ 3.1 - наблюдаемые значения (observables) в MobX

Тут все почти так же, как и в knockout. В примере ниже я использую синтаксис ES2016 и старше, потому что библиотека подразумевает использование новых средств языка:

```
import { observable, autorun } from 'mobx';

var result = observable("");

someInput.onchange = () => {
  result.set(someInput.value);
};

autorun(() => someDiv.textContent = result.get());
```

Однако, обычно в MobX используются классы, а не одиночные obervable:

```
class ViewModel {
  @observable result = "";
}

var vm = new ViewModel();

someInput.onchange = () => {
  vm.result = someInput.value;
};

autorun(() => someDiv.textContent = vm.result);
```

Comment: rxjs можно для полноты ещё..

Comment: async/await....

Comment: fibers/green threads..

Comment: @VladimirGamalian разве async/await уже поддерживается?

Comment: бабелем как минимум..

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Я бы сказал, только бабелем и поддерживается :) Возможно, вам следует написать свой ответ...

Comment: и свой вопрос )), не, седня меня не хватит на это

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, async/await пока даже в стандарте нет последнем, только `await` как зарезервированное на будущее ключевое слово

Comment: @Grundy абсолютно верное замечание. Специально зашел звездочку подкинуть на https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait

Comment: монументальный труд) ты что, ответ заранее записал а потом скопипастил в подходящий вопрос? уважаю.

Comment: @muturgan лол, посмотрите на автора вопроса :-)

Comment: тем более красавчик

Answer (score 24):

Код с асинхронными функциями можно исполнять синхронно используя альтернативный JS движок [nsynjs](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs)

### Если асинхронная функция возвращает promise

то просто вызываем функцию, а значение промиса получаем через свойство `data`:

```js
function synchronousCode() {

    var getURL = function(url) {
        return window.fetch(url).data.text().data;
    };
    
    var url = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js';
    console.log('received bytes:',getURL(url).length);
    
};

nsynjs.run(synchronousCode,{},function(){
    console.log('synchronousCode done');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/amaksr/nsynjs/master/nsynjs.js"></script>
```

### Если асинхронная функция вызывает callback

Шаг 1. Оборачиваем асинхронную функцию в nsynjs-обертку (либо в промис):

```
var ajaxGet = function (ctx,url) {
    var res = {};
    var ex;
    $.ajax(url)
    .done(function (data) {
        res.data = data;
    })
    .fail(function(e) {
        ex = e;
    })
    .always(function() {
        ctx.resume(ex);
    });
    return res;
};
ajaxGet.nsynjsHasCallback = true;
```

Шаг 2. Помещаем логику в функцию, как если бы логика исполнялась синхронно

```
function process() {
    console.log('got data:', ajaxGet(nsynjsCtx, "data/file1.json").data);
}
```

Шаг 3. Исполняем функцию через nsynjs

```
nsynjs.run(process,this,function () {
    console.log("synchronous function finished");
});
```

Nsynjs будет последовательно исполнять код функции, останавливаясь и дожидаясь результата вызовов всех аснихронных функций.

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. на дворе <s>2022</s> 2023 год и уже все активно пользуются async/await, то и примеры с ним.

Частая проблема возникает при следующей задаче:

1. Нужно получить какие-то данные в одном месте и потом использовать их в другом, но при этом между этими операциями может пройти время и они между собой могут быть не связаны одним контекстом или вызовом.

   Ответ прост: надо положить результат асинхронной функции в какую-то переменную и далее ей воспользоваться. Пример: есть методы `receiveData` (получить данные) и `renderChartsFromData` (отрисовать графики по полученным данным). Каждый метод вызывается **кликом по кнопке**. Один по одной кнопке, другой метод - по второй. Получается примерно такое:

   ```
    let chartsData = [];

    async function receiveData() {
        const response = await fetch('someUrl');
        chartsData = await response.json();        
    }

    function renderChartsFromData() {
        for (let item of chartsData) { ... }
    }

    document.getElementById('receive-data-btn').addEventListener('click', receiveData);
    document.getElementById('render-charts-btn').addEventListener('click', renderChartsFromData);
   ```

   Компактно и красиво. **Не надо смешивать всю логику в одном огромном методе**

   При этом проблема: пользователь может начать тыкать кнопку `renderChartsFromData` раньше получения данных. **Решение:** использовать "loader'ы" и/или дисейблинг/блокировку элементов управления пока выполняется операция. Логика может быть такая:

   - При вызове асинхронного метода включаем лоадер (например полупрозрачное **блокирующее окно на весь экран** с лоадером посередине и надписью "Пожалуйста, подождите..."). Лоадер можно повесить прямо в начале этого метода.
   - После окончания операции, в конце асинхронного метода, убираем лоадер.

   ---

   Пример при разделении логики на разные асинхронные методы:

   Есть методы: `userAllowedToSeeCharts`, `getData`, `renderCharts` и `showCharts`. Все они будут `async`. К примеру метод с именем `showChart` вызвается при клике на кнопку "show". Этот метод в себе последовательно вызовет `userAllowedToSeeCharts`,  `getData`, положит данные в переменную, отфильтрует данные как нужно и потом вызовет метод `renderCharts` с передачей отфитрованных данных. **Не забываем про лоадер**, чтобы пользователь не думал, что ничего не работает

   ```
    async function showCharts() {
        // --- Запускаем лоадер --- 

        let userIsAllowedToSeeCharts = await userAllowedToSeeCharts();

        if (!userIsAllowedToSeeCharts ) {                
            alert('Извините, вам нельзя это видеть');                            
        } else {
            let data = await getData();
            let filteredData = filterData(data);                                
            renderCharts(filteredData);                
        }

        // --- Выключаем лоадер --- 
    }

    async function userAllowedToSeeCharts() {
        const response = await fetch('someUrl');

        return await response.json();                    
    }

    async function getData() {
        const response = await fetch('someUrl');

        return await response.json();                    
    }

    function filteredData(data) { ... }

    function renderCharts(data) {
        for (let item of data) { ... }
    }

    document.getElementById('show-charts-btn').addEventListener('click', showCharts);
   ```
2. Хочу вывести в консоль (или внести в переменную) прилетевшие данные из асинхронного метода, но не захламляя сам метод этой консолью. А вне этого метода консоль/переменная показывает "промис". Например метод просто получает данные `getData` и складывает их в переменную

   Исходный код

   ```
   var url = 'https://somesite/api/v3/ticker/price?10';

   const getData = async (url) => {
       const response = await fetch(url);
       const jsonObj = await response.json();

       return jsonObj;        
   }
   ```

   Решение:

   ```
   const json = getData(url);
   getData(url).then(response => {
     console.log(response);
   });

   // Или так. Обёртку в виде функции ПРИДЁТСЯ написать
   // чтобы воспользоваться "await" для получения результата
   // зато НИКАКИХ "then"
   (async function() {
       let response = await getData(url);
       console.log(response);
   })();
   ```

Comment: Вопрос задан 6 лет 4 месяца назад. Изменён сегодня. =)) ничего против не имею, просто забавно))

Comment: @RuslanGorbunov это faq-вопрос, т.е. текущая проблема, с которой люди сталкиваются наиболее часто и тут собраны основные решения этой повсеместно возникающей проблемы. Парочка из этих проблем и решений в текущем ответе. Потому что нет смысла 1000 раз давать ответ на один и тот же вопрос. Они закрываются как дубликат с ссылкой на этот..... Да и обновить некоторые ответы тоже не лишне, с учётом развития технологий. Это нормально. Если бы вопрос и ответ были бы какими-нибудь заброшенными, то было бы странно это править или добавлять что-то